# Spring Boot REST test configuration

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I am making a REST api, in the @RestController I have the XML configuration with:

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource({"classpath*:applicationContext.xml"})
```

Inside the applicationContext, I have referenced the dataSource.xml on I have the connection to my embedded data base in memory. So I have this in the Controller:

```
//GET of customer
@RequestMapping(value = "/customer", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ListResults CustomerGET(@RequestParam(value="page", defaultValue="1") int page, 
@RequestParam(value="nregisters", defaultValue="15") int nregisters) {
    int ncustomers = custservice.getCustomers().size();
    List<Customer> customersbylimit = custservice.getCustomersbyLimit(nregisters*(page-1), nregisters);
    return new ListResults(customersbylimit,ncustomers);
}
```

With this I get a number of 'nregisters' customers from the MySQL database.

My problem is when I try to do the test of this method:

```
@Test
public void CustomerGET() {
    int npages, ncustomers;
    int nregisters = 10;
    boolean t;

    ncustomers = custservice.getCustomers().size();
    if(ncustomers%nregisters==0) npages = ncustomers/nregisters;
    else npages = ncustomers/nregisters+1;

    int page1 = 1;
    List<Customer> customers1 = custservice.getCustomersbyLimit(nregisters*(page1-1), nregisters);
    int page2 = 2;
    List<Customer> customers2 = custservice.getCustomersbyLimit(nregisters*(page2-1), nregisters);
    int page3 = 3; //In this case customers should be null
    List<Customer> customers3 = custservice.getCustomersbyLimit(nregisters*(page3-1), nregisters);

    if(page1>npages && customers1==null) t = true;
    else t = false;
    if(page2>npages && customers2==null) t = true;
    else t = false;
    if(page2>npages && customers3==null) t = true;
    else t = false;

    assertEquals("Not expected result",false,t);
    assertEquals("Not expected result", false, t);
    assertEquals("Not expected result",true,t); 
}
```

The line

```
ncustomers = custservice.getCustomers().size();
```

is returning me a NullPointerException and I think the reason is that the test is not configurated and it can't configure the database access... Somebody know how i can configure it or fix the problem?

Comment: Where are you initializing customers in custservice ?

Comment: How are loading config to test? Is it maven setup? In test you need to give path like @ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath*:applicationContext.xml"}) assuming applicationContext.xml is also in src/test/resources

Comment: CustmerService is the class where I implement the Repository on I have the getCustomersbyLimit function (is a HQL consult), but when I execute the controller in the console, everything goes fine, but in the test no..